# How does one find out the version of Apache Pig programmatically?

Tags: apache-pig, hue

I am using Pig through Cloudera's Hue (web interface), not through the command line. And, in fact, due to corporate restrictions, I have no access to the command line, but only to the Pig Shell itself through a the web interface.
I would like to find out my version of Apache Pig by means of some command that I can issue in the Pig language itself. 
Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can guess the version from the logs but if you put

> --version

as a 'Pig parameter' in the properties tab in the left box it will print:

> Apache Pig version 0.12.0-cdh5.3.0-SNAPSHOT (rexported)  compiled Sep
>   29 2014, 03:12:32
>
> Run pig script using PigRunner.run() for Pig version 0.8+ Apache Pig
>   version 0.12.0-cdh5.3.0-SNAPSHOT (rexported)  compiled Sep 29 2014,
>   03:12:32

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable in the properties file as follows:

```
PIG_VERSION `/home/hadoop/pig/bin/pig -version|head -n 1`
```

Those are backticks. Now in your script, PIG_VERSION will hold the version. In my case it holds:

```
Apache Pig version 0.12.0 (rexported)
```

A quick and dirty way to check the output is to try writing a file to 'SomeDirectory/$PIG_VERSION' and it will create a nested directory structure with each word.